# Returning filtered results from sql select

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, ssms, inner-join

For context this is a search that can be called by and end user, they will provide the comma delimited string containing the Table 3 ID's to be searched and Table 2 text value to search for.

I want to perform a select query that will only return matching results from the CTE where all values in the fieldValuePairTable match. Currently it returns any matches.

```
DECLARE @fieldvaluepairtable TABLE (Table3Id int, value varchar(max));
INSERT INTO @fieldvaluepairtable SELECT * FROM dbo.split_string_XML('123:york,456:halifax',',');

with cte as (
select Table1.id, Table3.id as t3id, Table2.text
from Table1
inner join Table2 on Table1.id = Table2.Table1Id
inner join Table3 on Table2.id = Table3.Table2Id)

select distinct id 
from cte
join @fieldvaluepairtable DataTable on (text like cast( '%' +  DataTable.value + '%' as varchar ) and t3id = DataTable.Table3Id)
```

For example;
A possible result set for the CTE looks like:

```
id   t3id  text       
---- ----- --------------- 
100  123   york            
100  456   halifax     
200  123   york                
200  456   manchester
```

The select statement would then return

```
id       
---- 
100
200
```

I want to select ID's where ALL values in fieldvaluepairtable match rather than when ANY match.
Meaning I want to see the following results

```
id       
---- 
100
```

The code will be used in a stored procedure so it needs to be able to handle any number of key value pairs being passed into the fieldvaluepairtable

Comment: Side Note, I really suggest replacing that delimited delimited (yep, I meant double there) value with a table type parameter.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would make this clearer.

Answer (score 0):

If I follow you correctly, you  can use some relational division technique:

```
select t1.id
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 
    on  t1.id = t2.table1id
inner join table3 t3 
    on  t2.id = t3.table2id
inner join @fieldvaluepairtable x 
    on  t3.text like cast( '%' +  x.value + '%' as varchar ) 
    and t3.t3id = x.table3id
group by t1.id
having count(*) = (select count(*) from @fieldvaluepairtable)
```

Basically this searches for matches, then groups the result by `t1.id`, and ensures that the number of rows in the group is equal to the count of search criteria.